# Java circuit breaker running in request thread

Tags: java, microservices, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I have been considering Netflix OSS circuit breaker solution - Hystrix.

Everything sounds good but I think that having the command run in a different thread does not make sense in my use case scenario.

That is because the work done by my request handler requires very little computation before calling the remote service. Also, there is nothing I can do while waiting for the response.

Example in Pseudo code:

@post("/token")
token(@body authResult){
  Validate authResult
  Get id from authResult 
  Call a remote service to get authz token
  Return authz token
}

I would like to do the remote call using hystrix but I do not think it makes sense to execute the command in a separate thread since I would be blocked anyway.

Any suggestions? Is it possible to run hystrix command in the same thread as the caller?

Comment: Can you show us what code you have attempted?

Comment: Just going by a quick read-through of the Netflix/Hystrix page, what they're describing sounds similar to Java Message Queues.  However I don't know enough about either to be really sure.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19435-01/819-0069/intro.html

Comment: There is 2600 forks of https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works . I would try to find something on the github. ALso spring.io has example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba Either you didn't get my question or I didn't get your answer. I am not asking how Hystrix works. I am asking if it can work without thread isolation, i.e. running in the same thread as he one serving the request.

Comment: Hi phil91. Agree. Did not fully understand your questoin. It might be worth editing it or at least showing the code you refer to.

Comment: The question feels a bit unclear. Why do you need to disable thread pooling? Also recommendations for other third party libraries is usually off-topic for SO. You need to edit this into a clearer problem statement

Comment: I have added an example and reformulated the question. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hystrix Command can run on the calling thread if you use SEMAPHORE as the execution isolation strategy

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#semaphores
https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#thread-or-semaphore

Comment: Yes. And [here](https://github.com/bijukunjummen/sample-spring-hystrix/blob/master/sample-hystrix-aggregate/src/main/java/agg/samples/commands/semaphore/SemaphoreClientCommand.java) is an example of how to do it. I have previously misunderstood the documentation.